# Bundle go app as a Mac app and intercept icon click

Tags: macos, go

the new version of [uTorrent](https://www.utorrent.com) is called uTorrent Web and it is developed with a smart cross platform UI idea. Basically, when you run the app, it keeps the uTorrent icon in the OS dock and opens a browser window with a nice interface and it is exposed by the local server (that is, the app itself). If you keep the app running, but close the browser tab, whenever you click again on the icon, it re-opens the app UI on "http://127.0.0.1:19575/". Very cool

I tried doing the very same thing with Go on MacOS. So, I wrote this super minimal app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

    // open the browser
    exec.Command("open", "http://localhost:8080").Start()

    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 10)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, os.Interrupt)
    <-sigchan
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello!")
}
```

Its starts a server that listens on :8080 and opens the browser. I then put the compiled app into a directory like this:

```
Test.app
  /Contents
    Info.plist
    /MacOS
      goapp
    /Resources
      icon.icns
```

`icon.icns` is the Mac icon file, `goapp` is the compiled Go app and the content of `Info.plist`
is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>goapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.pistacchioso</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Ta-da, it (almost) works. When I double click the directory, it fires up the app, I see its icon on the dock and it opens a browser page on `http://localhost:8080` where I con read "Hello!".

Now, my questions:

1. The icon keeps bouncing up and down as if it's still waiting for the app to fully start. Right clicking on it doesn't say "Exit" but "Force Exit". It sees the app as "stuck". How to solve this?
2. I also want to provide the "click on the icon the open the browser tab again". How to intercept said MacOS signal?